# Different behavior of malloc and free?

Tags: c, visual-studio, cygwin, malloc, free

I have a tree implemented in C++.

When I am running the code for creating the tree and inserting around 5,000,000 int keys using **malloc()**, it will take like **200MB** (as shown in **Task Manager**) when I am running using **Visual Studio 2013**.

When I am freeing the tree using **free()** on every node it will return to around **0.5MB**. Till now things are ok.

Now when I compile and run out of Visual Studio using **cygwin** the size of the tree becomes like **80MB** (which is ok because visual studio adds debugging info and other stuff), **but when I am freeing the tree nothing changes in its size!!!**

**In brief:** when running in Visual Studio freeing the tree returns the size of the program to the origional size 0.5MB but when I compile and run same code outside Visual studio (using cygwin) then freeing the tree doesn't change any thing from the size of the program still 80MB.

So why is this happening?

**Update**

After freeing the tree, I tried inserting same 5,000,000 int keys again in the tree. In case of cygwin it didn't use extra memory i.e. same 80MB that means as the feedback pointed out (thanks guys +1) that the memory is freed but not returned to the operating system.

**Now the question is:**
If I have huge allocation in memory, when freed I don't prefer to keep that freed area in the possession of the program. So how can I **force** cygwin to return it to the operating system?

Comment: It's difficult to measure "real memory consumption"; it's only very loosely related to C library functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB thank you for this point. Actually I am not interested here how much size it takes. I am only interested  in: why freeing the tree in Visual Studio returns the tree to its original size, while outside of Visual Studio nothing changes like it I am not freeing at all.

Comment: But that was part of my point: You cannot in general expect any sensible correlation between C library functions and "real" behaviour. It's perfectly feasible, say, for a desktop allocator to never return memory to the OS. All you can say about programming in C is what derives from the rules of the language.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks. So my friend is there a way to assure that 100% the memory is return to OS, because if you make a video game for example using such kind of code it will overflow the RAM because nothing is returned to OS.

Comment: @MosabShaheen it's virtual memory anyway.  You are over-analysing the issue. If you are freeing what you allocate and no longer need, and valgrind/whatever shows no serious problem with memory runaway, you're fine.  The Windows Task Manger is a high overview of a process memory allocation and knows nothing about your C sub-allocator.  Let the OS manage what it needs while you manage the malloc/free.

Comment: @KerrekSB please see the update above

Comment: @MartinJames thanks. Actually I didn't like the behavior of cygwin in case of huge allocation and freeing. I feel it is not good thing to take that much memory for the sake of reuse in the future which may not happen.

Comment: @MartinJames by the way when Task Manager shows the memory usage of the programs, it shows how much is virtual or physical memory taken?

Comment: @MosabShaheen depends.. goto 'View/Select Columns' and you can have several virual memory state values displayed.  IIRC, the 'default' is the size of all memory, code/stacks/heaps/whatever, currently actually loaded into RAM, ie. the 'working set', and so is a multiple of the page size, (4K).

Comment: @MartinJames is there a version of valgrind for Windows?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. Of course you write your application with correct resource use. Again, I didn't say that "all mallocs increase memory use"; rather, I said that malloc and free use don't generally correlate with "real world" observations -- at best, your *peak memory use* is observable, but if your application's allocator never releases any memory back to the OS (which is sensible on modern, paging and overcommitting OSs), the you'd only ever see a steady increase up to the peak use, and never a decrease. Of course if you write bad code that leaks, then you have no peak.

Answer (score 2):

The different mallocs behave differently.  Microsoft may use the raw heap to allocate and free items.

It seems that MS is using memory on the direct raw heap (HeapAlloc/HeapFree).

But cygwin, is using a local managed memory system.

That means freeing through HeapAlloc / HeapFree will return the memory to the operating system, and free the associated resource.

calling free on cygwin, will return the memory to be re-used, but not give it back to the operating system.

### Managing large amounts of memory

If you have large amounts of memory which need to be handled, then you will be better off managing them directly, by iteracting with the operating system, and calling its primitive functions.  On Windows for example, you can call HeapCreate, to create a separate heap, and allocate  within that separate large block allocations using HeapAlloc, freeing them with HeapFree.

When you are finished with the block, all of the memory can be freed with HeapDestroy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. So in this case how can I return the memory to the operating system when using cygwin (even I tried compiling and running in Linux and it didn't free the tree)

Comment: I would not worry about it too much.  The memory is there for your program to re-use, and the memory will be un-mapped, if other programs need memory.  The memory is returned, when your program exits

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically requesting the host system for memory, and releasing it, can be expensive operations, due to the need to interact with other processes (e.g. context switches associated with making requests to privileged device drivers that actually manage the hardware resources).

To reduce such a performance hit hit, `malloc()` (and `calloc()`, etc) and `free()` can manage a pool of allocated memory internally, in order to avoid the expense of going to the operating system every time memory is requested or released.   For example, if `free()` is called, it might simply change an internal data structure to record that block of memory is no longer in use by the program, but not actually inform the operating system that the memory is released.

`malloc()` may also deliberately over-allocate as well. For example, it may request several kilobytes at a time from the host system, even if the program requests much less, and then parcel that block out for multiple `malloc()` calls, rather than making a request to the operating system for every call of `malloc()`.

With `malloc()` and `free()` working in such ways, as far as the operating system is concerned, the memory usage by the program may not reduce on a call of `free()` (at least until the code of `free()` ACTUALLY decides, according to its own criteria, to return the memory to the host system).   There may also be effects, on multiple calls of `malloc()`, of memory usage increasing sharply at first, and then leveling out, even if the program is calling `malloc()` many times with no calls of `free()`.

Comment: Re your update:   in standard C, it is not possible to force any implementation to release memory back to the host.   You'll need to read documentation for your particular compiler and library to find IF it provides a (non-standard) means of doing that.    I've never come across any documentation even suggesting cygwin provides such a capability.

Answer (score 0):

Generic memory allocators use various heuristics to try and optimize common allocation/deallocation patterns, but they must handle all cases correctly.

In your particular case, you may be eligible for a much simpler approach if your problem has the following properties:

- you allocate many objects with the same size.
- you allocate them in a single phase.
- you free all objects at the same time

You can use a custom allocator for this where nodes are allocated and freed in batches. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *left, right;
} Node;

typedef struct NodeBlock {
    struct NodeBlock *next;
    size_t count, size;
    Node a[32768];
} NodeBlock;

Node *alloc_node(NodeBlock **node_heapp) {
    NodeBlock *ptr = *node_heap;
    if (!ptr || ptr->count == ptr->size) {
        ptr = calloc(sizeof(*ptr, 1);
        if (ptr == NULL)
            return NULL;
        ptr->size = sizeof(ptr->a) / sizeof(ptr->a[0]);
        ptr->next = *node_heap;
        *node_heap = ptr;
    }
    return &ptr->a[ptr->count++];
}

void free_nodes(NodeBlock **node_heapp) {
    while (*node_heapp) {
        NodeBlock *ptr = *node_heap;
        *node_heap = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

The above code allocates nodes in large batches:

- allocation is more efficient as it makes very few system calls and uses a trivial method to return the next available slot.
- the overhead is very small.
- deallocation is very quick too as one does not need to walk the tree to deallocate individual nodes.
- It may also have good properties on Unix systems because `malloc()` is likely to use `mmap()` for large requests, surrendering the memory back to the system upon deallocation. If you do not observe this, try increasing the blocking factor (the length of the `Node` array `a`).